# How do I access Game Keys in the Desura Client?

Tags: desura

After activating or buying a Game via Desura, you can view your Keys for the game itself or other Digital Distribution Services on [this](http://www.desura.com/collection) page.

But how do you access this page in the Desura Client?

Comment: I found it, but I'm going to see if there's a quicker way to get to it.  For the record, the Desura client could still use a lot of work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never actually used this section of Desura before, but it's called the 'Collection'.  It doesn't appear to have a dedicated navigation spot in the client, but I found how to get to it anyway.  Worth noting is that the Desura client is largely a glorified web browser that uses the Desura website as the content.

---

- Go to your 'Gifts History' section through the dropdown menu at the
  top, or through the footer at the bottom of any non-library page.

`History > Gifts History`

[image: Dropdown navigation to gifts]

## OR

[image: Footer Naviagation]

---

- Then click the link to your collection.  It's near the top.

[image: Collection link is near the top]

---

Why you can only get to it through the gifts section, I have no idea.  It does seem quite strange.  Hopefully they streamline the client some more eventually, although it's been pretty unchanged for quite a while.